# Regex to Find values with quotes,Semicolon and Equals to

Tags: regex, linux, unix, regex-negation

My Query is simple and my concern is very simple and very new to REGEX.
I'm trying to match the records with Double quotes .

```
Example :

This is my sample Record :

"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"1556562030","ServerName":"XYZ_U_O","deletedat":"2018-08-24 17:56:39.974"}


{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 17:56:34.944"}
```

First record is valid record with Serverserial and Server Name, But the second record is invalid with 0 as server serial and empty ServerName.

I want to match the second record to eliminate the records . 
I did try this it is matching both the records.

```
**^(?=.*?\bdelete\b)(?=.*?\bServerName\b).*$**
```

With my expertise I couldnt do it . Can anyone help me to resolve this huddle

Comment: Basically, like this? https://regex101.com/r/l5Q4Fr/1 BTW: Is your input JSON?

Comment: my INput format is JSON . How did you solve it in two minutes . I was working on this for hours . How can I lean that like you . Simple and Neat .

Comment: Also I have missed one thing in my samples , At the end of JSON there will be a comma , That also should be eliminated . {"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 17:56:34.944"},{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":"","deletedat":"2018-08-24 17:56:34.944"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add this as a full answer..

- Just search for the fixed part of the string in question and use it as front-anchor,
- then match till the first curly bracket.
- As requested, I've added an optional comma (if case the undesired data shows up at the end)

```
{"eventType":"delete","ServerSerial":"0","ServerName":""[^}]+},?
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l5Q4Fr/3)**

Answer (score 0):

This will match any line that has a server name of `""` or a server serial of `0`

`.*(?<=ServerSerial":")0(?=").*|.*(?<=ServerName":")(?=").*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l5Q4Fr/2)